# What is a simple example of Lorentz invariant equation?

Tags: special-relativity, covariance, invariants

The algebraic criteria for proving Lorentz invariance is that, replacing x with x' and t with t', where

$$x'=\gamma(x-vt)$$
$$t'=\gamma\left(t - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right)$$

should give back a certain "similar" form of the original equation.

*What is the simplest toy equation that can be easily shown to be Lorentz invariant algebraically?*

Comment: How about $E=mc^2$ (where the quantity $E$ here refers to the energy in the rest frame, and $m$ refers to the invariant mass).

Comment: $1=1\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: @AndrewSteane where should I put the variables x and t into $E = mc^2$?

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə where should I put the variables x and t into 1 = 1?

Comment: What do you mean by Lorentz-invariant? Maxwell's equations are not invariant, they are covariant. The terms in the equations are not invariant. Do you just mean an equation true in any inertial frame of reference?

Comment: @ProfRob yes, i think I meant that Maxwell's equations have the same form in any inertial frame of reference. But I have not done a concrete example how an entire physical law can be invariant in every aspect under Lorentz transformation, so I don't really know what that means.

Comment: Voting to close since "the simplest" is probably opinion-based. Could also be closed as "homework like" or unclear.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/741266/how-to-generate-invariant-quantities-using-4-vector-method

Answer (score 4):

$\Delta t^2-\Delta (x/c)^2=\Delta s^2$ for Minkowski spacetime geometry,
in analogy to $\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2=\Delta r^2$ for Euclidean geometry

Answer (score 2):

Is there a formal definition of simplest? I'll posit:

$$ E^2 -(pc)^2 = (mc^2)^2 $$

which you can Lorentz transform to $|\vec p| = 0$ and get:

$$ E = mc^2 $$

Of course there is the notion of "Manifest covariance" (which is manifest invariance for Lorentz scalars like $m$), in which covariance is apparent in Minkowski space:

$$ p^{\mu}p_{\mu} = (mc)^2 $$

where the 4-momentum is:

$$ p^{\mu} = (E/c, \vec p) $$

Answer (score 1):

Finding invariant equations in special relativity is relatively easy once you know about contra/covariance.

Define a contravariant vector as any vector which transforms as
$$V'=\Lambda\cdot V^\nu$$
where
$${\Lambda}=\pmatrix{\gamma&-\beta\,\gamma\\
-\beta\,\gamma&\gamma}$$
Is the Lorentz matrix. Contravariant vectors are often denoted with a superscript index, like $V^\mu$.
Now define a covariant vector as a vector which transforms as $V'=({\Lambda^{-1})^T}\cdot V$, here $\Lambda^{-1}$ is just the inverse of the Lorentz matrix and you can find it by replacing $\beta\rightarrow-\beta$. Here $^T$ means taking the transpose. Contravariant vectors are often indicated with a subscript index, like $V_\mu$.

Now every time you contract a contravariant vector with a covariant vector you get an expression which is invariant under Lorentz transformations. A contraction is then defined using either of these expressions $V\cdot W=V_\mu W^\mu=V^TW$.
\begin{align}
V'\cdot W'&=V'_\mu W'^\mu\\
&=((\Lambda^{-1})^TV)^T \Lambda W\\
&=V^T\Lambda^{-1}\Lambda W\\
&=V^TW\\
&=V\cdot W
\end{align}
If you have a contravariant vector you can easily construct a covariant vector by contracting it with ${\eta_{\mu\nu}}=\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1}$. For example if you contravariant vector is $(ct, x)$, your covariant vector is $(-ct, x)$. Contracting these gives $-c^2t^2+x^2$, which is invariant.

Answer (score 0):

The quantity

$$x^2 - c^2t^2$$

is algebraically invariant under the transformation:

$$x'=\gamma(x-vt)$$
$$t'=\gamma\left(t - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right)$$

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please replace your photo with equations typeset with MathJax.

Comment: @robphy yes I will, as soon as I have an hour to spare :)